# How to write correctly call and parse values to a setter method that accepts input variable of Calendar.Builder type

Tags: java, calendar

Cannot correctly update a date field by using the class instance to invoke the setter method (setSchoolStartDate()). The classwork requires that the SchoolStartDate and SchoolEndDate must be of type Builder.
Question: Can the below be achieved?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    School obj1 = new School();
    obj1.setSchoolStartDate(SchoolStartDate);
```

the full code is below:

```
    import java.util.Calendar.Builder;
    import java.util.List;

    public class School {
    private String SchoolName;
    Builder SchoolStartDate;
    Builder SchoolEndDate;
    private List<Frequency> SchoolFrequency;

   //Getters and setter methods for the variables
    public void setSchoolName(String SchoolName) {
    this.SchoolName = SchoolName;
    }

    public String getSchoolName() {
    return SchoolName;
    }

     public void setSchoolStartDate(Builder SchoolStartDate) {
    this.SchoolStartDate = SchoolStartDate;
    }

public Builder getSchoolStartDate() {
    return SchoolStartDate;
}

public void setSchoolEndDate(Builder SchoolEndDate) {
    this.SchoolEndDate = SchoolEndDate;
}

public Builder getSchoolEndDate() {
    return SchoolEndDate;
}

public void setSchoolFrequency(List<Frequency> SchoolFrequency) {
    this.SchoolFrequency = SchoolFrequency;
}

public List<Frequency> getSchoolFrequency() {
    return SchoolFrequency;
}
// @overloaded constructor 1- parameterized

/**
 * @param SchoolName
 * @param SchoolStartDate
 * @param SchoolEndDate
 * @param SchoolFrequency
 */
public School(String SchoolName, Builder SchoolStartDate, Builder SchoolEndDate,
        List<Frequency> SchoolFrequency) {
    this.SchoolName = SchoolName;
    this.SchoolStartDate = SchoolStartDate;
    this.SchoolEndDate = SchoolEndDate;
    this.SchoolFrequency = SchoolFrequency;
}

// @overloaded constructor 2- default
public School() {

}
```

Comment: *The classwork requires that the SchoolStartDate and SchoolEndDate must be of type Builder.* A very peculiar requirement. And even more so since the `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated and certainly shouldn't be taught in any classes anymore.

Comment: What is the expected result of your `main` method? In particular, which value should the start date of `obj1` have after the call to `setSchoolStartDate`?

Comment: The expectation is that the instance of the school class (obj1) can all the setSchoolStartDate and update the date.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Maybe because you didn't understand my question?

Answer (score 0):

Either your teacher misunderstood, or you have misunderstood the class work. It doesn’t make any sense to represent dates as `Calendar.Builder`. Furthermore the `Calendar` class is poorly designed and long outdated, so we should not use it, let alone teach it, this includes not using the nested `Calendar.Builder` class.

### java.time

Instead use `LocalDate` from java.time for representing a date. This poses no problem. For example (not tested):

```
public class School {
    // More instance variables here
    LocalDate startDate;

    public void setStartDate(LocalDate startDate) {
        this.startDate 0 startDate;
    }

    public LocalDate getStatrtDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    // more methods
}
```

Use for example like this:

```
    School obj1 = new School();
    obj1.setStartDate(LocalDate.of(2019, Month.SEPTEMBER, 1));
```